# Position social buttons in bootstrap nav bar Wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Need a little fixing the position of my social icons to the right in my navbar. Any tips will be much appreciated thanks.

Example:

```html
<nav class="blog-nav">
      <div class="floating-box">
      <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
           'menu'              => 'primary',
           'theme_location'    => 'primary',
           'depth'             => 2,
           'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
           'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
           'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
         );
       ?>
      </div>
      <div id="nav-social" class="floating-box">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

[image: Pic]

Comment: To help people who might be able to answer your question, you might want to clarify what you're trying to achieve, and where your attempted solution is falling short. In the pic you attached, the social buttons *are* "to the right". Are they simply not far *enough* to the right (i.e., you want them right-aligned)? Or does the picture represent the desired outcome?

Comment: Hi, yes should of clarified, want the social icons only pulled to the far right of the navbar, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the class="floating-box" to class="pull-right" ? maybe that works, otherwise change the class of the menus to class="pull left"

so you kinda pull them apart

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll give that a try and let you know how if it worked.

Comment: alright, let me know ;). I'm kinda new to bootstrap too, but i just searched it

Comment: Genius Mr.thatguy, the class="pull-right" worked a treat, thanks :)

Comment: No problem haha, mark it as the correct answer please? ;D